# how to count the number of nodes in a binary tree with only one child?

Tags: java

I have implemented the following function:

```
public int count(Node n) {
    if (n == null) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n.left == null && n.right != null) {
        return 1 + count(n.right);
    } else if (n.left != null && n.right == null) {
        return 1 + count(n.left);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I called it with:

```
System.out.println(tree.count(tree.root));
```

It only prints me the value of the root. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A binary tree with only one child is just a unary tree, aka a `LinkedList`. Shouldn't your implementation handle both `left` and `right`? It also looks like your method should be `static`

Comment: Step through your code manually and ask what happens if `left` and `right` are both non-null.

Comment: Please paste the full code class instead of the single count. The problem should not be in this count method except that the final 'return 0' should be 'return 1' because the leaf node should be count 1 if no left node and no right node.

Comment: In the last return statement, you just replace "return 0" --> "count(n.right) + count(n.left)", It will work.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to have elements of both an instance method and a static method, which is a bit confusing. Choose one, and be consistent in similar methods. The simplest way is to use the bitwise xor `^` (returns `true` if **exactly one** of the two expressions are `true`)

This is a `static` method. Called using `Node.countNonBranchingNodes(tree)`:

```
public static int countNonBranchingNodes(Node n) {
    if (n == null) return 0;
    return (n.left != null ^ n.right != null ? 1 : 0) +
           countNonBranchingNodes(n.left) +
           countNonBranchingNodes(n.right);
}
```

If you want an instance method version, call this using `tree.countNonBranchingNodes()`:

```
public int countNonBranchingNodes() {
    int count = left != null ^ right != null ? 1 : 0;
    if (left != null) count += left.countNonBranchingNodes();
    if (right != null) count += right.countNonBranchingNodes();
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I am bit confused in your instance method count(), If a node is having both left and right nodes, still you are counting it, but the problem statement is that we have to count no. of nodes which has exactly one child, Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: @pbajpai21 Ah, you've got a point there. The name of the method is very misleading.

Comment: Actually, you should initialise count =1 only If that node  has only one child, but in your code you are always initialising count as 1, so even If the node is leaf node or the node is having both left and right children, the current  node is still being counted which will give incorrect answer.

Comment: great,,I was looking for this only, now your logic is perfect..:)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you forget to handle the node which has both left and right child, so your code should like this:

```
public int count(Node n) {
    if (n == null) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n.left == null && n.right != null) {
        return 1 + count(n.right);
    } else if (n.left != null && n.right == null) {
        return 1 + count(n.left);
    } else {
        return count(n.left) + count(n.right);
    }
}
```

Comment: your code will fail at: return 1 + count(n.left) + count(n.right);

Comment: @pbajpai21 Care to explain why you think that would fail?

Comment: @Erwin, sorry for that, actually here the problem statement is that to count the nodes which are having exactly one child, but in this answer even if the current node is leaf node or having both left and right child in that case also we are counting the current node and adding 1 always, which will give incorrect answer, please look at my answer, may be you can understand better then.

Comment: @Erwin thank you for your noticing and I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have not handled the case when node is having both left and right children. In that case we have to avoid that node to be counted but still we have to further proceed with counting in left and right subtrees. But in your solution, If the node if having both the children, then you are simply returning 0, that's not correct.

```
    public int countNodesWithExactlyOneChild(Node root){
        if(root == null) return 0;
        return (havingOneChild(root) ? 1 : 0) +
                   countNodesWithExactlyOneChild(root.left) + 
                   countNodesWithExactlyOneChild(root.right);

    }

    private boolean havingOneChild(Node node) {
        if(node != null && ((node.left == null && node.right != null) ||
            (node.left != null && node.right == null))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to give the recursive methods the correct name.

Comment: The ternary operator has the lowest precedence other than assignment operators. The ternary should have parentheses around it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your node will have 5 possibility:

"left only", "right only", "both left and right", "neither left nor right" and "null".

```
public int count(Node n) {
    // null
    if (n == null) {
        return 0;
    // right only
    } else if (n.left == null && n.right != null) {
        return 1 + count(n.right);
    // left only
    } else if (n.left != null && n.right == null) {
        return 1 + count(n.left);
    // both left and right
    } else if (n.left != null && n.right != null) {
        return count(n.left) + count(n.right);
    // neither left nor right
    } else if (n.left == null && n.right == null) {
        return 1;
    // any else missing?
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are missing only one line

this one should work :

```
public int count(Node n) {
    if (n == null) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n.left == null && n.right != null) {
        return 1 + count(n.right);
    } else if (n.left != null && n.right == null) {
        return 1 + count(n.left);
    }
    return (count(n.left) + count(n.right));
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).